# Does guardian shield affect brood lord attacks?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg, starcraft-protoss

Pretty self explanatory. As I understand, the broodlings from a broodlord have two different attacks: the first attack is an air attack (using air upgrades), and subsequent attacks are melee ground attacks.

I guess guardian shield has no effect for those subsequent attacks, but what about the first attack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Team Liquid](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Ranged) the Brood Lord does count as a ranged unit, but is **not** affected by guardian shield.

Secondly, like you mentioned, all subsequent attacks by the broodlings are melee and are also not effected.